# Why does docker create empty node_modules and how to avoid it?

Tags: node.js, docker

There are some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651908/why-node-modules-is-empty-after-docker-build) but they haven't answered why docker creates the empty `node_modules` directory in the repo even though the dockerfile is setup to hold node_modules in the container?

I'm interested to know why directory is created on the host empty, give that yarn already installs packages inside the container within `node_modules` and how to avoid it.

```
## Dockerfile

FROM node:8.11.4-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add yarn
RUN yarn global add nodemon
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json yarn.lock /usr/app/
RUN yarn

EXPOSE 3000
```

```
## docker-compose.yml

version: "3.2"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: nodemon index.js
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: You have `/usr/app/node_modules` mounted. Remove the line and it would work well. Did you add `/usr/app/node_modules` intentionally?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are right, your image building process is installing the node packages into the `node_modules` directory in the image. So, after you build your image the image contains `node_modules` and you can use it to run your application.

You see `node_modules` on your host machine, because of your volumes setup in your Compose file. There is more to it than you see in the other answer though.

What's happening is that you are mapping `.:/usr/app` in your first volume definition, which means that you are mapping your current directory on the host to `/usr/app` in the container.

**This will override the `/usr/app` directory in the image with the current directory on the host. And your host does not have the `node_modules` directory (unless you installed node_modules on the host, too) and therefore your container will not work with this mapping, beacuse you've overriden `/usr/app` and there is no `node_modules` dir in the override.** Node will throw an error that it cannot find node modules.

The next volume mapping solves the situation, this is actually a common Node development setup. You create a volume `/usr/app/node_modules`. Note, that this volume does not have a host part there is no `:` in the mapping, there is only one directory here. This means that Docker will create an anonymous volume, on first start up copy the `/usr/app/node_modules` directory from the image, and add it to the previous mapping where you mapped the host dir to `/usr/app`.

**So in the running container you'll have your source code from the host's current directory PLUS `node_modules` from the underlying image due to the double mapping.**

**As a side effect you'll see an empty `node_modules` directory in your host's current directory.**

Comment: Thank you, that really helps, in learning these things, the random empty folder gives you a sense that you've done something incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know if there is a way for the IDE to have access to the `node_modules` without hard-copying it?

Comment: I managed to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61137716/8966651