# Why does docker-compose create an empty host folder when mounting named volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
volumes:
    - .:/var/www/app
    - my_modules:/var/www/app/node_modules
```

I do this because I don't have `node_modules` on my host and everything gets installed in the image and is located at `/var/www/app/node_modules`.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. An empty folder gets created in my host named `node_modules`. If I add another volume (named or anonymous) to the list in my `.yml` file, it'll show up in my host directory in the same folder that contains my `.yml` file. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278208/3813411) answer, it seems to have to do with the fact that there's these two mappings going on simultaneously. However, why is the folder empty on my host? Shouldn't it either a) contain the files from the named volume or b) not show up at all on the host?
2. How does Docker know to check the underlying `/var/www/app/node_modules` from the image when initializing the volume rather than just saying "Oh, `node_modules` doesn't exist" (since I'm assuming the host bind mount happens before the named volume gets initialized, hence `/var/www/app` should no longer have a folder named `node_modules`. It seems like it even works when I create a sample `node_modules` folder on my host and a new volume while keeping `my_modules:/var/www/app/node_modules`—it seems to still use the `node_modules` from the image rather than from the host (which is not what I expected, although not unwanted).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an implementation detail, Docker actually uses the Linux kernel filesystem mount facility whenever it mounts a volume.  To mount a volume it has to be mounted on to a directory, so if the mount target doesn't already exist, it creates a new empty directory to be the mount point.  If the mount point is itself inside a mounted volume, you'll see the empty directory get created, but the mount won't get echoed out.

(If you're on a Linux host, try running `mount` in a shell while the container is running.)

That is:

- `/container_root/app` is a bind mount to `/host_path/app`; they are they same underlying files.
- `mkdir /container_root/app/node_modules` creates `/host_path/app/node_modules` too.
- Mounting something else on `/container_root/app/node_modules` doesn't cause anything to be mounted on `/host_path/app/node_modules`.
- ...which leaves an empty `/host_path/app/node_modules` directory.

[The first time you start a container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container), and only then, if you mount an empty volume into a container, the contents from the image get copied into the volume.  You're telling Docker this directory contains critical *data* that needs to be persisted for longer than the lifespan of the container.  It is not a magic "don't use the host directory volume" knob, and if you do things like change your `package.json` file, Docker will not update the contents of this volume.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One thing that seems to not make sense is how if I run `docker-compose up -d` and then `docker-compose stop`, remove `node_modules` from the host, and then do `docker-compose up -d`, when I `ls` I see the empty `node_modules` folder again. I thought this wouldn't happen since the container isn't being recreated. Hence, if the container isn't being recreated and it's just being started again from a stopped state, I would think the folder wouldn't be created again in the host.

Comment: I have created a followup question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317302/does-stopping-docker-compose-containers-unmount-volumes).