# Does stopping docker-compose containers unmount volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

As part of my quest to completely understand how docker deals with volumes under the hood (followup from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56285283/3813411)), I'm curious about how running `docker-compose stop` deals with volumes.

There are two possibilities that I suppose may happen:

1. Volumes are unmounted after running `docker-compose stop` and then mounted again in lexographic order when running `docker-compose start`.
2. Volumes stay mounted until the container is removed using `docker-compose rm` or a similar command.

I was curious as even restarting a stopped container will create an empty directory in my host folder. I have the following in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
- .:/var/www/app
- my_modules:/var/www/app/node_modules
```

So, from my understanding of the answer in the linked post above, the empty directory is created because of the following:

1. Bind mount happens first (lexographic order), overwrites everything in `/var/www/app`
2. Docker will try to mount `node_modules`, but since the directory no longer exists in the container (overwritten), it will `mkdir node_modules` to have a directory to mount the named volume.
3. Since the bind mount already exists when the `mkdir` happens, I see a new, empty `node_modules` folder in my host.

This makes complete sense if the volumes are being mounted, but if 2) is true and they stay mounted even after running `docker-compose stop`, why would I still be seeing an empty directory being created in my host? I remove `node-modules` from my host in between the `stop` and `up` command for reproducing this behavior.

Comment: Docker never removes anything. Period, you don't want your data lost.

Comment: @emix thank you, however that's not quite what I'm asking. I'm asking about the implementation regarding whether stopping containers using `docker-compose` ends up unmounting (not talking about removing—I know it doesn't remove) the volume, and if not, why I'm seeing the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not allowed to **rmdir**(2) a directory that's a mount point in use; so if you can remove the directory, the volume isn't mounted.

Comment: @DavidMaze I can't do `docker volume rm node_modules`, for example, since it says that there's a container in use. Though i don't know if that means necessarily it's mounted. I'm wondering do you think that because remove it in my host after `stop`ping the container, when I restart, that deletion is reflected in the container and since it needs the directory to mount the named volume, it will run `mkdir` again regardless of if it's remounted? I know it's such a minor detail but the whole process I find intriguing.