# kubernetes volumes for nestjs app for hot reloading data

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm having an issue with volumes on Kubernetes when I'm trying to mount hostPath volumes. (i also tried with PVC, but no success)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN yarn install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "start:dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: always
    labels:
      kompose.volume.type: 'hostPath'
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: task-management
```

api-development.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose -f docker-compose.yml convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.1 (HEAD)
    kompose.volume.type: hostPath
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: api
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: api
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose -f docker-compose.yml convert
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (HEAD)
        kompose.volume.type: hostPath
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: task-management_api
          name: api
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/src/app
              name: api-hostpath0
            - mountPath: /usr/src/app/node_modules
              name: api-hostpath1
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /Users/handrei/workspace/devs/nest-ws/task-management
          name: api-hostpath0
        - hostPath:
          name: api-hostpath1
status: {}
```

the error I received from the pod is the next one:

kubectl logs api-84b56776c5-v86c7

```
yarn run v1.22.17
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/usr/src/app"
```

I assume that's something wrong with volumes because applying the deployment and service without volumes it's working

Comment: A `hostPath` volume mount will mount a directory from whichever random node the container happens to be running on; it's not a reliable way of getting data or source code.  I'd avoid trying to use a clustered container system like Kubernetes as a live development environment; instead, use Node locally for day-to-day development and use a self-contained image (without any volume mounts at all) in Kubernetes.

Comment: Ok, I used that method with docker-compose, and I wanted to try it on Kubernetes too, but if you say this is not the way of doing it, I'll believe you :) thanks a lot

Comment: The other thing you'll find, if you're trying to translate a Compose setup into Kubernetes, is the `node_modules` directory is empty and nothing in Kubernetes will every copy data there.  You'll need to delete all of the volume declarations from your Deployment spec for this to run.

Comment: thanks a lot @DavidMaze. i managed to make it run

Answer (score 2):

> A  [`hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)  volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's filesystem into your Pod.

To the required  `path`  property, you can also specify a  `type`  for a  `hostPath`  volume.

> **NOTE**: HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a best practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a HostPath volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required file or directory, and mounted as  **ReadOnly**.

---

As @[David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) mentioned before, It's better idea to

> use Node locally for day-to-day development and use a self-contained image (without any volume mounts at all) in Kubernetes. (...)
>
> The `node_modules` directory is empty and nothing in Kubernetes will every copy data there. You'll need to delete all of the volume declarations from your Deployment spec for this to run.

---

[This quide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/) will help you to translate a Docker Compose File to Kubernetes Resources.

See also this questions on StackOverflow:

- [Why *node_modules* is empty after docker build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651908/why-node-modules-is-empty-after-docker-build)
- [Kubernetes volume for *node_modules*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910919/kubernetes-volume-for-node-modules)

Comment: thanks a lot man. I already start using node as local development.